# How do I stop HashMap from overwriting previous value for a key?

Tags: java, hashmap

With my code, the new value overwrites the value stored previously against the same key.

This is my code:

```
HashMap<String, String> meMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
meMap.put(p.getName(), selState);
```

Comment: ["A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) Putting a new value with an already-present key will overwrite the previous value.

Comment: so i can't insert dynamically more values into hash map?

Comment: You can make your value type a `Collection<String>`, and insert multiple values into the collection.

Comment: i must put an id for all object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hashmap overwriting values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807952/hashmap-overwriting-values)

Answer (score 1):

If the key is same for all then you should map key to list of values: `Map<String, List<String>>`

And then to update list of values mapped to a specific key:

```
List<String> values = map.get(key);
values.add("new");
map.put(key, values);
```

Comment: i have keys different....so how i can put dynamically into map more "key,object"?

Comment: @markella if you have different keys, the HashMap will keep both key-value pairs. But it is clear that you putting same keys with different values.

Comment: i have different keys and some values....

Comment: so if i write only one time "                            meMap.put(p.getName(), selState);
" it not overwrite?

Comment: @markella if `p.getName()` equals an already stored key, old value will get overwritten.

Comment: if p.getName() equals an already stored key, old value will get overwritten ok, but if p.getname() is a new key, this new key not override key stored before?

Comment: If the key is not the same it shouldn't override old value. New key-value entry should be added.

Comment: @markella the above comment explained very well. Do you understand it now?

Comment: ok, now i understand

Comment: @sufian but if i want iterate hash map into another function how can i pass hash map as argument?

Comment: @markella just like you'd do with any other variable.

Comment: @markella public void myMethod(Map<String, String> mapParam) { } - method signature which accepts a Map.

Answer (score 0):

The `HashMap` is a pair key/value object. It can be only one value for a given key.

If you try to put the same key that already exists, you will be replacing the existing value for that key.

If you want to add a new value, you have to give a new key to that value.

Comment: but key is same for all....

Comment: i must put an id for all object ?

Comment: So, you don't want a `HashMap` to solve your problem. If you need multiple values for the same key, you can insert any kind of `Collection` of `String` for each key (assuming you have more than one key in your `HashMap`).

Comment: yes i have more than one key in my hasmap